# How to scribe when the filler offcut piece isn't itself square?

Tags: wood, filling, scribing

I have an offcut that isn't exactly square and parallel, but it does have one straight side along the length. Think of something like this:

[image]

I'm wanting to use this as a filler piece between my bookcase and the ceiling.

I have one of the [u-scribe jigs](https://www.u-scribejig.co.uk/) to help with scribing, however I can't figure out the best way to achieve what I'm after. I have used the u-scribe jig for other jobs where I've had a parallel, square offcut to use, I'm just not sure in this situation. I can't find much in the way of instructions from them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a woodworking site that might have more expertise in specialty stuff like this.

Comment: That would be [woodworking.se]. You can make an easy link, @nobody by typing `[woodworking.se]`. Works for any of the SE sites.

Comment: This is a carpentry question, not a woodworking question.

Comment: Rather than asking how to use your gizmo, maybe revise to show the situation or describe it better. It's difficult to answer beyond the general advice FreeMan has given you.

Comment: I dunno, scribing a cabinet carcass to fit seems to be as much woodworking as carpentry. I'm not suggesting a migration or VtC in either case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really sure what the filler piece not being square/parallel/whatever has to do with any of it.

You say you've got one straight edge. That edge will go against the straight edge of the bookcase. The other edge, no matter how ragged it is, goes against the ceiling and all that raggedness gets cut away and a new "raggedness" (that precisely matches the ceiling profile) gets added.

I'm not really sure what the point of that u-scribe jig is<sup>*</sup> (I just took a brief look at their site). All you really need to do to scribe is to ensure that your straight edges are parallel, that the narrowest point of your scribe board is sufficient to fill the gap to the ceiling, then use a compass [like this one from u-scribe](https://www.u-scribejig.co.uk/collections/all-products/products/pencil-compass-and-scriber) (or any cheap Dollar/Pound Store version) to run along the ceiling and make a line on the filler piece.

Cut along the filler piece with a bit of a back bevel (makes it much easier to fit the scribed piece in), then install.

<sup>*</sup>I've gone back and looked at that product several times now and still have no clue what it's for or how to use it. I guess UK installers just come with the knowledge of how to use that gizmo built in, and it's likely well above the heads of us US-based folk... :shrug:

Comment: I've found it to be pretty handy. It screws into the back of your filler piece and the 'chair legs' of it go over the side of your furniture piece (they do different sizes to match the thickness of common boards like 18, 15, 12mm) so that it's supported and kept in place while you do your scribing. The only issue I have with them is like I highlighted in my question... There's next to no good instructions for it, save a 30 minute Youtube video that I don't want to have to sit through each time I want to use them.

Comment: If you're looking for someone to write up instructions, @physicsboy, then you're probably in the wrong place. Instead, why don't you watch it one more time, write up your own instructions, then keep them with your u-scribe brackets. That way it's a quick read instead of a 30 minute watch...